# System folder not visible

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have role named "GCP US Alias and Redirect" and I have given full access permission for "/sitecore/system/Aliases" and its descendants as in screen shot below.

[image: Access Viewer]

Now I have assigned "GCP US Alias and Redirect" role to a user, When I login to sitecore as "GCP US Alias and Redirect" user I don't see "/sitecore/system" folder. I can just see "/sitecore/content" folder as in below screen shot.

[image]

I can see System folder when searched it by GUID as shown in below screen shot.

[image]

What do I do to make it visible at initial place when I open content editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to the `View` tab and select `Hidden items` and `Entire tree` checkboxes. They are unchecked by default for non-admin users.

If you don't see the `View` tab, make sure that either your role has `Read` access to it  (`/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Ribbons/Default/View` and `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/View` in `core` database) or that your role inherits from e.g. `sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing` role (check if that role doesn't have too much access rights for your custom role first).

[image]

Comment: View tab is not visible for "GCP US Alias and Redirect" user. Hidden Items are checked when I viewed it in admin user.

Comment: Yes - `Hidden Items` are checked for admin. They are **unchecked** for `non-admin` users by default. Does your role inherits from any other roles?

Comment: Answer updated - check "Entire tree" checkbox as well.

Comment: I don't see View tab for "GCP US Alias and Redirect" user. It does not inherit any other roles

Comment: Answer updated. Explanation how to show View tab added

Comment: Now I am able to see View tab after I gave read permission for View ribbon in Core data base for "GCP US Alias and Redirect" user. Now I am even able to see System folder. Thanks for the help.